# How to suppress only the long form of an argument in the argparse help output?

Tags: python, argparse

When I'm using argparse, as an example like this:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", action="store")
```

then the help menu is like this:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-i INPUT]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INPUT, --input INPUT
                        input file
```

What should I do if I don't want the `--input INPUT` here? Like this:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-i INPUT]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INPUT              input file
```

Comment: Drop `"--input"` in `add_argument()` if you don't want to offer it at all.

Comment: but I want that `-i INPUT` there @BradSolomon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have two options with the same destination attribute, and use `argparse.SUPPRESS` to suppress the help text for one of them.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", dest="input", action="store")
parser.add_argument("--input", dest="input", action="store", help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `--input` from `add_argument` to remove that option and add `dest='input'` to keep `INPUT` in the help text

```
parser.add_argument("-i", dest='input', action="store")
```

Comment: He wants `--input` as a usable option, he just wants it out of the help text.

Comment: @Barmar Nowhere did the OP say that. (It said that it wanted `-i INPUT`, but no reference to `--input`.) I agree that your answer is the most complete, but there is no need to question other answers that fulfil the requirements.

Comment: He asked "What should I do if I don't want the --input INPUT here?" I interpreted "here" as referring to the help output.

Answer (score -1):

Set the `dest` name used to store the value:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser                                             
parser = ArgumentParser()                                                       
parser.add_argument("-i", dest="input", help="input file", action="store")      
parser.parse_args()
```